# postgresql fetch 100 random rows

Tags: performance, random, postgresql-9.1

The following query takes around 300-400ms on postgresql 9.1.
The table contains ~2M rows.
Is this performance justified? Can it be improved?

```
SELECT "Products"."Id"
      , "Products"."Title"
      , "Products"."ThumbHeight"
      , "Products"."LargeImageWidth"
      , "Products"."LargeImageHeight"
      , "Products"."Url"
      , "Products"."BrowseNodeId"
FROM "Products"
WHERE  "Products"."Id" = ANY(ARRAY(SELECT (random()*2233071)::int
                FROM generate_series(1, 100)));
```

And here is the explain plan:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Bitmap Heap Scan on "Products"  (cost=60.48..100.46 rows=10 width=268)
   Recheck Cond: ("Id" = ANY ($0))
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=1000 width=0)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Products_pkey"  (cost=0.00..42.97 rows=10 width=0)
     Index Cond: ("Id" = ANY ($0))
```

Explain analyze:

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on "Products"  (cost=60.48..100.46 rows=10 width=268) (actual time=77.702..80.944 rows=100 loops=1)
   Recheck Cond: ("Id" = ANY ($0))
   InitPlan 1 (returns $0)
     ->  Function Scan on generate_series  (cost=0.00..17.50 rows=1000 width=0) (actual time=0.097..0.348 rows=100 loops=1)
   ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Products_pkey"  (cost=0.00..42.97 rows=10 width=0) (actual time=77.601..77.601 rows=104 loops=1)
         Index Cond: ("Id" = ANY ($0))
 Total runtime: 81.409 ms
```

Id is the primary key:
    `"Products_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree ("Id")`

Thank You!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution which works well for my use case (select 100 random products for a web page):

1. Duplicate the table
2. Shuffle table rows
3. Add auto increment column
4. Select from a random range (e.g 100-200, 1567000-1567100)

Query time went down under **2ms**.

Here is the set of commands I've used:

```
create table RandProducts as select * from "Products" order by random();
alter table RandProducts add column RandId serial8;
create index on RandProducts(randid);
```

And then to get 100 random rows I just do something like this:

```
select * from Products where RandId between 8000 and 8100;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in comparison to your query:

```
SELECT "Products"."Id"
      , "Products"."Title"
      , "Products"."ThumbHeight"
      , "Products"."LargeImageWidth"
      , "Products"."LargeImageHeight"
      , "Products"."Url"
      , "Products"."BrowseNodeId"
FROM "Products"
ORDER BY random()
LIMIT 100
```

Comment: This is the worst solution when you are looking for performance, especially for large tables.